# Left outer join in HIVE causing an error

Tags: sql, database, hive, left-join

I am trying to perform a left outer join on 2 tables in Hive. The join condition here involves a `LIKE` operator. This is the query that I am trying to execute:

```
SELECT *
FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM b  
     WHERE class = 'ex') ON b.mo LIKE CONCAT(a.device_name ,'%')
                         AND a.time_stamp BETWEEN to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(cast(b.first_time AS BIGINT) - 660), "z")
                                          AND to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(cast(b.first_time AS BIGINT) + 60),"z")
```

When I execute this query, I get an error

> Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN ''%''

The aim here to perform a left outer join on the tables a and b on the given conditions i.e. based on the device name and `time_stamp`.

If someone could help me out with this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`like` isn't supported in the `join` conditions. One way around this is to specify the condition in the `where` clause.

```
SELECT * --better specify columns needed instead of *
FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * from b  WHERE class = 'ex') b ON 1=1
WHERE b.mo LIKE CONCAT(a.device_name ,'%')
AND a.time_stamp 
BETWEEN to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(cast(b.first_time AS BIGINT) - 660),"z")
AND to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(cast(b.first_time AS BIGINT) + 60),"z")
```

But the problem with this approach is, the `join` turns to an `inner join` as you are filtering the right table (b in this case).

Comment: So there is no way I could perform the left outer join with the LIKE condition ?

Comment: no, as far as i know..you can't use `like` even with a `inner join`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Just to expand on this a bit, Hive (actually it's map reduce, but anyhow...) can only support equi-joins for outer joins - `table1.col = table2.col`.  You can't use like, between, > or <, etc.  Any of those will result in that incredibly non-informative error of `Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN`.